# Parsing JSON array and object in Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

This is what the JSON looks like:

```
[{
    "pmid": "2",
    "name": " MANAGEMENT",
    "result": "1",
    "properties": [
        {
            "prop_id": "32",
            "prop_name": "Bonneville",
            "address": "122 Lakeshore",
            "city": "Ripley",
            "state": "OH",
            "zip": "11454",
            "lat": "41.123",
            "long": "-85.5034"
        }
    ]
}]
```

I am trying to parse it with the following Java code in Android:

JSONObject jObj = null;
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

```
    // We get weather info (This is an array)
    JSONArray jArr = jObj.getJSONArray("properties");

    // We use only the first value
    //JSONObject JSONWeather = jArr.getJSONObject(0);
    JSONObject c = jArr.getJSONObject(0);
    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
    String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
    String phone = c.getString(TAG_PHONE);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return null;
```

I am not getting any results though. How can I successfully parse this JSON? I'm using Android Studio.

Also, if there were multiple pieces to the array, how could we make sure each one of them is printed out?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your JSON string start with JSONArray.

Here sample code, try it.

```
    JSONArray mJsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
    JSONObject mJsonObject = mJsonArray.getJSONObject(0);

    String pmid = mJsonObject.getString("pmid");
    String name = mJsonObject.getString("name");
    String result = mJsonObject.getString("result");


    JSONArray mJsonArrayProperty = mJsonObject.getJSONArray("properties");
    for (int i = 0; i < mJsonArrayProperty.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject mJsonObjectProperty = mJsonArrayProperty.getJSONObject(i);

        String prop_id = mJsonObjectProperty.getString("prop_id");
        String prop_name = mJsonObjectProperty.getString("prop_name");
        String address = mJsonObjectProperty.getString("address");
        String city = mJsonObjectProperty.getString("city");
        String state = mJsonObjectProperty.getString("state");
        String zip = mJsonObjectProperty.getString("zip");
        String lat = mJsonObjectProperty.getString("lat");
        String lon = mJsonObjectProperty.getString("long");
    }
```

Check [Android JSON Parsing Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/)

Comment: This prints out one result, thank you for that. I am wondering, if it is not too much... how can I print all entries out, if there are multiple prop_id for example?

Comment: this is for loop so you can add all data in list

Comment: Okay, what if the JSON was   [{"pmid":"2","name":"MANAGEMENT","result":"1","properties":[{"prop_id":"32","prop_name":" Tower","address":"281 Lakeshore","city":"Euclid","state":"OH","zip":"44142","lat":"54.5","long":"-81.5034"}]},{"pmid":"1","name":"ONE","result":"18","properties":[{"prop_id":"3","prop_name":"Chase","address":"146 Goon Blvd.","city":"City","state":"OH","zip":"12345","lat":"46.35","long":"-83.1138"},{"prop_id":"6","prop_name":"Club Apartments","address":"4600 Barrington Club","city":"Columbus","state":"OH","zip":"43520","lat":"40.436","long":"-83.048"}]}]

Answer (score 2):

As in posted json String `jsonStr` is *JSONArray of JSONObeject's instead of JOSNObject of JSONArray*.

So convert `jsonStr` String to `JSONArray`:

```
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
JSONObject c = jArray.getJSONObject(0);
// get properties JSONArray from c
 JSONArray jArrProperties = c.getJSONArray("properties");
 JSONObject jsonObject = jArrProperties.getJSONObject(0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is complete example with resolution.

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
     JSONObject jObj = null;
    try {
        String jsonStr = "[{\"pmid\":\"2\",\"name\":\" MANAGEMENT\",\"result\":\"1\",\"properties\":[{\"prop_id\":\"32\",\"prop_name\":\"Bonneville\",\"address\":\"122 Lakeshore\",\"city\":\"Ripley\",\"state\":\"OH\",\"zip\":\"11454\",\"lat\":\"41.123\",\"long\":\"-85.5034\"}]}]";
        jsonStr = jsonStr.substring(1, jsonStr.length()-1);
          System.out.println(jsonStr);
        jObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);



        System.out.println("pmid="+jObj.get("pmid"));
        System.out.println("name="+jObj.get("name"));
        System.out.println("result="+jObj.get("result"));


        JSONArray jArr = jObj.getJSONArray("properties");

        JSONObject c = jArr.getJSONObject(0);

        System.out.println("prop_id=="+c.get("prop_id"));
        System.out.println("prop_name=="+c.get("prop_name"));
        System.out.println("address=="+c.get("address"));
        System.out.println("city=="+c.get("city"));
        System.out.println("state=="+c.get("state"));
        System.out.println("zip=="+c.get("zip"));
        System.out.println("lat=="+c.get("lat"));
        System.out.println("long=="+c.get("long"));


    } catch (JSONException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

in this exammple details object contain j son data

```
                  JSONObject details = mJSONParser.doInBackground(); //json object                
                  Child_Registration_StaticData deta=new Child_Registration_StaticData();
                    try
                    {
                        deta.UniqueID = details.getString("UniqueID");
                        deta.Nameofchild= details.getString("Nameofchild");
                        deta.FatherName= details.getString("FatherName");
                        deta.DOB= details.getString("DOB");

                        child_name.setText(deta.Nameofchild);
                        father_name.setText(deta.FatherName);
                        dateof_birth.setText(deta.FatherName);
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your root object is a JSON array `[]`, not a JSON object `{}` there. So, you need

```
jObj = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
jObj = jObj.getJSONObject(0);
```

The rest of your code will now work fine treating `jObj` as a `JSONObject`. The concept here is exactly the same as what you're doing for your `properties` JSON array.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
try {
            JSONArray array0 = new JSONArray(Sample);
            JSONObject object0 = array0.getJSONObject(0);
            JSONArray array1 = object0.getJSONArray("properties");
            JSONObject object1 = array1.getJSONObject(0);
            String name = object1.getString("prop_name");


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```