# Inconsistency in loading multi layered Json file from android studio

Tags: android, json

Am new to using json files and I have constructed a layered  json object  and i am trying to display the values in android studio Toast but some of the values which are key and I don't want them to be displayed yet  but they are getting displayed in the process please guide on what am doing wrong

This is portion of the json file (single object in the json array)

```
 {
    "county": "Nyeri",
    "subcounty": ["Kieni East", [{
        "ward": ["funny", [{
            "policestation": ["null"]
        }], "kkkkk", [{
            "policestation": ["null"]
        }]]
    }], "Kieni West", [{
        "ward": "null"
    }], "Mathira East", [{
        "ward": ["Magutu", [{
            "policestation": ["Magutu", [{
                "arbitrator": ["null"]
            }], "Magutu ps", [{
                "arbitrator": ["null"]
            }], "Kagochi PS", [{
                "arbitrator": ["null"]
            }]]
        }], "Iriani", [{
            "policestation": ["null"]
        }], "Konyu", [{
            "policestation": ["null"]
        }], "Kirimukuyu", [{
            "policestation": ["null"]
        }], "Karatina Town", [{
            "policestation": ["Kagochi PS", [{
                "arbitrator": ["null"]
            }], "Gitunduti PS", [{
                "arbitrator": ["christopher bundi", "silvester kasanga"]
            }]]
        }]]
    }], "Mukurweini", [{
        "ward": "null"
    }], "Tetu", [{
        "ward": ["rulie", [{
            "policestation": ["null"]
        }]]
    }]]
 }
```

This is the code and trying to access the subcounties with excluding the keys to the wardslist

```
  try {
  JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray (response);

 for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length (); i++) {
   JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject (i);

  String subcounty = jsonObject.getString ("subcounty");
  Toast.makeText (getApplicationContext (), subcounty, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show ();}//close try and catch follows
```

The challenge is to select the subcounty value exempting those values that are key to ward. 
Thank as you offer support

Comment: the JSON format is not correct, first element of your JSON array is string and second is a JSONArray

Comment: how should i structure the json to achieve the impression of  ... counties under it listing of subcounties in it...then for every subcounty the listing of wards in it and so on . Thank you as you offer the support

Comment: you can add Json object inside Json array and 1 son object can contain name:"country name", sub:[array of sub countries] e.g
[{"name":"Kieni East", "ward": ["sub1","sub2","sub3"] },{"name":"Kieni West", "ward": ["subWest1","subWest2","subWest3"] }]

Comment: I hope you know how JSON works, each {} represents an object and [] represents array. objects contains value pairs i.e key:value. for more details https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp

Comment: Thank you sir hfarhanahmed am working on such structure  and i will give the feedback

Comment: let me know if it works for you so I can post it as an answer

Comment: [object Object]how should i loop through it please

Comment: I am not sure what exactly do you want to do, can you explain?

Comment: my intention are that  after loading different objects in each array i use the list to cascade   spinners i.e when i select a county the spinner for subcounty should load relate subcounty. On selecting a subcounty the relevent wards should be loaded and so on. what i am unsure of is how many OnItemSelectedListener  are need please can you give me an idea@ hfarhanahmed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code and JsonFormat, I hope this will help.

```
String response = "[{"name":"Country 1", "subs": ["sub1","sub2","sub3"] },{"name":"Country 2", "subs": ["subWest1","subWest2","subWest3"] }]";
        try{
            JSONArray mainList = new JSONArray(response);
            ArrayList<String>   countries   =   new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<String>   subs   =   new ArrayList<>();

            for (int a=0;a<mainList.length();a++){
                JSONObject object=mainList.getJSONObject(a);
                countries.add(object.getString("name"));
                subs.add(object.getString("subs"));
            }

            setAdapterForCountries(countries);
        }catch(JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

on Item select callback do this

```
////On Item Select
            JSONArray   subCountries    =   new JSONArray(subs.get(selectedItemPosition));
            setSubCountiresAdapter(subCountries);
```

This is how you get a string list from that JSONArray.

```
private void setSubCountiresAdapter(JSONArray   subs){
    ArrayList<String>   subsNames   =   new ArrayList<>();
    for (int a=0;a<subs.length();a++){
        try {
            subsNames.add(subs.getString(a));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By revising the array into correct format i.e
[{
    "county": "Mombasa",
    "subcounty": [{
        "subcountyname": "mtwapa",
        "ward": [{
            "wardname": "funny",
            "policestation": [{
                "stationame": "Magutu ps",
                "arbitrator": [{
                    "arbitratorname": "christopher bundi"
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        "subcountyname": "likoni",
        "ward": [{
            "wardname": "null"
        }]
    }, {
        "subcountyname": "hihi",
        "ward": [{
            "wardname": "null"
        }]
    }, {
        "subcountyname": "mambo",
        "ward": [{
            "wardname": "null"
        }]
    }]
}, {
    "county": "Kwale",
    "subcounty": [{
        "subcountyname": "null"
    }]
}]
then i can access data from the array by looping
through the objects in initial array.
the at this level with the object subcounty i can get the array in it,,,the get the object subcounty name in that array and so on for better clarity refer [Parsing JSON array and object in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28736419/parsing-json-array-and-object-in-android)